# Always call a function with +1 higher than last call?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Each time the `input_function()` is called the argument needs to be one integer higher than the last time it was called. It can't be modified.

In the below example the first iteration works, but on the second it will be called with the argument of `4` which should have been `5`.

```
input_function(1)
input_function(2)

for i in 1..4
  input_function(2+i)
  # do something here with i
  input_function(3+i)
  # do something here with i
end
```

**Question**

How can I make sure that the argument for `input_function()` is always one higher than the last time it was called?

The solution can be in any langauge.

Comment: Why so many languages? Can't do the coding challenge yourself?

Comment: If there's only one valid input for the function, why can't the function just assume that input? This seems like a very strange design.

Comment: Because it is an algorithm problem ans those languages are close to the one I need it in.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes That doesn't mean you spam tags... decide to use language and stick to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to keep the state of the function

```js
var input_function = (function() {
  var last_argument = null;
  return function(input) {
    if (last_argument !== null && input !== last_argument + 1) { 
      throw new Error('invalid input argument: ' + input)
    }
    last_argument = input;
    console.log('input OK', input);
    // do something here?
  }
})();

input_function(4);
input_function(5);
input_function(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually I would use [static variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) for this kind of problem. Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't support it. If you want to do something similar in Javascript, you can recurr to this alternative:

```
function input_function(n) {
    alert(n + count.num);
    count.num++;
}

// initialize count number
count.num = 0;

input_function(10); // alert 10
input_function(4); // alert 5
input_function(1); // alert 3
```

Source: [DeluxeBlogTips](http://deluxeblogtips.com/missing-way-to-create-function-static/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript may not support static variables per se but functions in JS are first class objects and therefor they can have properties that can be used like statics. Reworking the above example:

```html
function input_function(n) {
    alert(n + input_function.count++);
}

input_function.count = 0;

input_function(10); // alert 10
input_function(4); // alert 5
input_function(1); // alert 3
```